# How to select a DC cable connection type based on current?

Tags: power, batteries, current, dc, connector

**I have a battery and DC-DC converter solution that I've ordered. The solution will output 20A continuously at 5V, and will sometimes pulse up to 30A for durations up to 10 seconds.**

I believe voltage is not a big concern here.

**How would one go about selecting the appropriate connector for such a battery solution and DC power cables attached to it, given the current that it must tolerate?**

From my research, 2.1mm barrel jacks cannot handle this level of current (they typically range from unspecified current to 5A).

For my 20A continuous, 30A pulse requirement, an model SD45 connector was recommended by the battery manufacturer:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the connectors used for UPS batteries.  They handle similar currents.

Comment: Figure your wire size first. There are two limits to wire size. One, will the wire heat up and melt the insulation or start a fire? Google "ampacity tables." Two, will the power loss or voltage drop in the wire prevent my circuit from functioning correctly? For this, you need to have a target and know the  length of wire. So once you select your wire diameter, you can look for appropriate connectors. For me, for this power level, I would use through-hole mount screw terminals. Anything that can accept the wire size you end up using will work.

Answer (score 2):

You show a picture of an Anderson Power Pole connector.  The smallest of these is rated at 30 Amps continuous and they go up past 200 Amps.  They are inexpensive and reliable.  We use the 60A and 100A versions in a couple of products.